# Length of maximal chain between meet and join

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

My recent research is straying slightly into order theory, and I keep encountering a measurement which surely is defined in the literature, but so far I cannot find terminology anywhere.

Suppose $L$ is a **lattice**, i.e., a poset in which any two elements have a unique **meet** (greatest lower bound, denoted by $\wedge$) and a unique **join** (least upper bound, denoted by $\vee$).  For $a,b \in L$, is there terminology in the literature corresponding to the following definition?

The _____ of $a$ and $b$ is the length of a maximal chain between $a \wedge b$ and $ a \vee b$.

I know that this may not be well-defined in all lattices, but I am mainly concerned with sublattices of Young's lattice (a.k.a. dominance lattice), in which I believe it is well-defined, since the length of a maximal chain between two Young diagrams is just the difference of the diagrams' sizes (ranks).

Comment: I don't know a standard name. You might introduce the word "distance". That is: The distance from $a$ to $b$ is the length of a maximal chain between $a\wedge b$ and $a\vee b$.